# what is a single-valued association in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have doubt when i am reading difference resource for **Proxy fetching** or **"No-proxy" fetching** they are called Single-Valued association in (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html).what is a single-valued association in hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single value association means when you used property tag(i mean to use java primitive types) then that field is only associated with one value. But when you used many-to-one or any collections like bag, set, list or map, they are associated with whole object not with any primitive data type of java.